# Call AlertDialog on a specific date each year

Tags: android, date, calendar, android-alertdialog

I try to call AlertDialog on a certain date every year when launching an app that day that is defined but something fails and I ask for your help. Note, for example, on November 11 of each year, it is necessary to run AlertDialog all day when launching the app, and when November 12 start, AlertDialog will not be displayed until November 11 of the next year. Thanks in advance.

```
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    start.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 11);
    Date today = start.getTime();
    if(start.equals(today)){
        showStartDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = start.getTime();
start.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.NOVEMBER, 11)
if(start.getTime().equals(today)){
   showStartDialog();
}
```

Or you can just

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = start.get(Calendar.MONTH)
int dayOfMonth = start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
if (month == Calendar.November && dayOfMonth == 11) { ...}
```

Comment: Do you have any more solution because this doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you call `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` and `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`?

Comment: Date today = start.getTime();
    if(calendar.equals(today)){
        showStartDialog();
    }

Comment: I don't understand your logic. You are changing the calendar and move it to 11 November and then you are if the calendar is equal the date. `start` is a calendar while today is a Date they will never be equal